Look for specific value in csv file using batch
I have a data.csv file that looks like this:
1,a
2,b
3,c
4,d
5,e

I need to make a batch file where you input a number and it retrieves the value in the column next for that row in this csv file. So for instance, if you input "3" the script will output "c".
I figured the first step would be to define the input as a variable using SET /P, and then use that variable to look for the output using a simple array:
@echo off
SET /P variable=Enter a number 
FOR /F "delims=," %variable IN data.csv DO @echo %%b
PAUSE

But that doesn't seem to work. Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

I would advise you to read the documentation of the commands you are trying to use before asking questions. You have several syntax issues with the FOR command. Open a command prompt and type: FOR /?

The following works for me – using the sample file in your question. According to that file, the number entered by the user exists only once and is immediately followed by a comma (,).
SET /P variable=Enter a number
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`findstr /b "%variable%," data.csv`) DO (SET str=%%F)
CALL SET result=%%str:%variable%,=%%
echo %result%


findstr returns the line, in file data.csv that contains the number entered by the user.
the line found is stored in str
result contains the part of the line found that comes after the comma

Refer to the following:

findstr
How to set commands output as a variable in a batch file
How-to: Edit/Replace text within a Variable

EDIT
In above code, pattern supplied to findstr was changed according to suggestion in comment by @Stephan. Rather than just "%variable%", it is now "%variable%,". Also /b option added to findstr command.

will give you false results when searching (for example) 2, if there is a line 26,z. Better change to findstr /b "%variable%," to match only the one relevant line.

we both know that "sample data" is a reduced set of examples. This will very likely become relevant to the asker. It wasn't a critique, but a simple add-on information.
